# ReadDirectoryChangesW unable to detect and handle deletion of watched directory

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pywin32, readdirectorychangesw

I try to monitor the contents of a directory tree, which my contain a huge ammount of files (many directories with 9000 files per directory as an example).

> Synchron mode:

I first tryied using *ReadDirectoryChangesW* in blocking mode (synchronous), but when I delete the watched directory I end up in a deadlock which I can't detect nor exit.

```
#
# Monitors a directory for changes and pass the changes to the queue
#
def MonitorDirectory(self, out_queue):

    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' is watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))

    # File monitor
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

    buffer = win32file.AllocateReadBuffer(1024 * 64)

    hDir = win32file.CreateFile(self.path,
                                FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                None,
                                win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                None)

    # Monitor directory for changes
    while not self._shutdown.is_set():

        # Create handle to directory if missing
        #if os.path.isdir(self.path):

        self.fh.write("ReOpen Exists {0}\n".format(os.path.isdir(self.path)))
        self.fh.flush()
        try:
            hDir = win32file.CreateFile(self.path,
                                FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                None,
                                win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                None)
        except:
            self.fh.write("Handle is dead\n")
            self.fh.flush()

        try:
            self.fh.write("{0}\n".format(newH))
            self.fh.flush()
        except:
            self.fh.write("Write failed\n")
            self.fh.flush()

        self.fh.write("Check Changes\n")
        self.fh.flush()

        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                                                    1024 * 64,
                                                    True,
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
                                                    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                                                    None,
                                                    None)

        # Add all changes to queue
        for action, file in results:

            self.fh.write("Action: {0} on {1}\n".format(action, file))

            out_queue.put((action, time.time(), os.path.join(self.path, file)))

        self.fh.flush()


        #else:


    # Done main loop
    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' has finished watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))
```

there just seemed to be no way to avoid the call from blocking when the watched directory is removed?

Also as the function is running in a thread, I cannot kill it when deadlocked, from a "supervisor" thread which would monitor the parent directory for DELETE actions on the watched directory and I dont really like that being a good solution as it involves much more code.

> ASynchron mode:

I then tried the overlapped mode (async) which does not block in a deadlock, but I can't detect when the directory handle becomes void as the diorectory is deleted. 
The *WaitForSingleObject* call just time's out, and checking if the directory is present with *os.path.isdir* does not help because if the directory is recreated in the mean time, it will not return False, but the old directory handle is still invalid and will not detect the changes in the newly created directory with the same name.

Afer days of trying various approaches, I finnaly got to this code, which however does not work flawlessly bacause it still does not detect the removel of the watched directory and it also does miss a few files when mass deleting files rapidly. A thing which the sync mode did not.

```
#
# Monitors a directory for changes and pass the changes to the queue
#
def MonitorDirectory(self, out_queue):

    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' is watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))

    # File monitor
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

    overlapped          = pywintypes.OVERLAPPED()
    overlapped.hEvent   = win32event.CreateEvent(None, False, 0, None)

    buffer  = win32file.AllocateReadBuffer(1024 * 64)

    # Main loop to keep watching active
    while not self._shutdown.is_set():

        # Open directory
        try:
            hDir = win32file.CreateFile(self.path,
                                        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                        None,
                                        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                        win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | win32con.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                        None)

        except: 

            # Wait before retry
            time.sleep(1)

        else:

            # Monitor directory for changes
            while not self._shutdown.is_set():

                win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                                                buffer,
                                                True,
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                                                overlapped,
                                                None)

                # Wait for the changes
                rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, 10000)

                if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                    try:
                        bytes_returned = win32file.GetOverlappedResult(hDir, overlapped, True)

                    except:
                        raise Exception("Error: handle invalid?")

                    else:

                        # Get the changes
                        for action, file in win32file.FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION(buffer, bytes_returned):                        
                            out_queue.put((action, time.time(), os.path.join(self.path, file)))

                elif rc == win32event.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\': Timeout, no actions")

                else:
                    raise Exception("Error?! RC = {0}".format(rc))

    # Done main loop
    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' has finished watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))
```

Is there a way to handle the detection of the removal of the watched directory, instead of just removing the *win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE* flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Considerations

- 1<sup>st</sup>, I invite you to read [[SO]: win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't find all moved files
  (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799109/win32con-and-win32file-not-finding-all-moved-files/49888600#49888600), for general considerations regarding [[ActiveState.Docs]: win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32file__ReadDirectoryChangesW_meth.html) (which wraps [[MS.Docs]: ReadDirectoryChangesW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw)). I will place here some aspects from the other answer (the ones that are really important)
- Always aim for **asynchronous** because it allows gracefully exit on timeout (**abnormal interrupt might keep open resources locked till program exit** (and sometimes even beyond!))
- Don't use threads because of *GIL* ([[Python.Wiki]: GlobalInterpreterLock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock))

Now, a few words on *FILE_SHARE_DELETE* (could find some doc about it on [[MS.Docs]: CreateFileW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)):

The golden rule (or immutable law, if you will) is that **user can't *really* delete a file (or *dir*) that has open handles**.

Attempting to delete or rename (this seems irrelevant for the current problem, but it isn't) a *dir* with open handles might have different results (depending on the way that the handles were created and the *API* used to rename / delete the *dir*):

1. Error (*ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED*) - happens when *FILE_SHARE_DELETE* wasn't specified (and some other cases)
2. No error, but the dir is still there - generally means that it was scheduled to be deleted, and will automatically disappear once its **last open** handle will be closed
3. Success and the *dir* is deleted. Actually, that's not true, the *dir* is just moved (renamed) to "*RECYCLE.BIN*" (attempting to remove it from there will result in ***#1.***; so would attempting to *really* delete it in the 1<sup>st</sup> place (<kbd>Shift + Del</kbd> from *Explorer*))

I tested the above scenarios trying to delete / rename the *dir* in various ways:

- *cmd*: `rmdir /q /s`, `move /y`
- *Explorer*: <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + Del</kbd>
- *Windows Commander*: <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + F8</kbd>

I started to investigating ways to fix your problem and I came across [[MS.Docs]: GetFinalPathNameByHandleW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) (*win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle*). Played with it:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> import os
> >>> import win32api
> >>> import win32file
> >>> import win32con
> >>>
> >>> print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test']
> >>> test_dir = ".\\test"
> >>> os.path.abspath(test_dir)
> 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test'
> >>> h = win32file.CreateFile(test_dir, win32con.GENERIC_READ, win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE, None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING, win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, None)
> >>> h
> <PyHANDLE:620>
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test'
> >>> test_dir1 = test_dir + "1"
> >>> os.rename(test_dir, test_dir1)
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test1']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test1'
> >>> os.rename(test_dir1, test_dir)
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test'
> >>> os.unlink(test_dir)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\test'
> >>> # Delete the dir from elsewhere (don't use os.rmdir since that will only schedule the dir for deletion)
> ...
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-5-21-1906798797-2830956273-3148971768-1002\\$RY7SH8D'
> >>> os.mkdir(test_dir)
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-5-21-1906798797-2830956273-3148971768-1002\\$RY7SH8D'
> >>> os.rmdir(test_dir) # Since the new "test" dir wasn't open, operation successful
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-5-21-1906798797-2830956273-3148971768-1002\\$RY7SH8D'
> >>> # Restore the dir from RECYCLE.BIN
> ...
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test'
> >>> os.rmdir(test_dir) # Still an open handle, scheduled to be deleted
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py', 'test']
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> '\\\\?\\E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q049652110\\test'
> >>> win32api.CloseHandle(h)
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['code00.py'] # After closing the handle the dir was deleted
> >>> h
> <PyHANDLE:0>
> >>> win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> pywintypes.error: (6, 'GetFinalPathNameByHandle', 'The handle is invalid.')
> ```

**Note**: I also tried [[MS.Docs]: GetFileInformationByHandle function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle) (*win32file.GetFileInformationByHandle*), but I couldn't reproduce the behavior, not even with one of the 3 *pywintypes.datetime* fields (which should be the Last access / modify time); when renaming / deleting the *dir*, none of the info changed. I didn't spend time to investigate, I thought of 2 possible reasons:

- That data is somehow stored "inside" the *HANDLE*, and the function doesn't actually query the *FS* when invoked (as opposed to *GetFinalPathNameByHandle*)
- When the *dir* is renamed / deleted, those date fields change for its parent *dir*(s)

So, we seem to have a winner. I'm only going to post the algorithm (the code should be fairly simple):

- After *CreateFile*, call *GetFinalPathNameByHandle* on the handle and save it in a variable
- In the loop (that constantly calls *ReadDirectoryChangesW*), at each iteration (*WAIT_TIMEOUT*) call *GetFinalPathNameByHandle* again on the handle and compare the result with the saved value; if they differ (the *dir* was renamed / "deleted"), then take the appropriate measure, e.g.:

  - Break out of the loop
  - Reopen (recreate) the *dir* and start over
  - Let the user know

Other possible approaches (although undesirable):

- Don't specify *FILE_SHARE_DELETE* (as you noted), that way the *dir* will be *unrenameable* / *undeleteable*
- Monitor the parent *dir* (as *ReadDirectoryChangesW*):

  > Retrieves information that describes the changes within the specified directory. The function does **not** report changes to the specified directory itself.
- As the parent *dir* might contain other *dir*s / files that you don't care about, I thought of a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*) that might or might not work:

  - Pick a *dir* (totally different than the ones we talk about)
  - Create a *symlink* of our *dir* to monitor inside (you control that *dir*, no one else will mess around with it)
  - Monitor it (here I know neither whether events are forwarded through a *symlink*, nor how monitoring reacts when breaking the link)

Regarding "event loss", as I specified in the other answer, there's no way to be sure that all of them will be processed, there are only ways to minimize the lost ones number.

Comment: Wow, that waas precise! also I missed the Recyclebin part, that does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for the records: The Solution (and explanation of the issue) by CristiFati did the trick.

In fact there where 2 issues:

When simply deleting the file, it was moved to the recycler, so the handle was in fact still valid but changes where not tracked anymore. Using `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` did the trick! I could detect the deletion, and handle accordingly.

Secondly when deleting the file without going to the recycler, there was an error because the file was still visible in the folder but innaccessible, such that subsequent calls to `CreateFile` failed with access denied error. That was due to the fact that the previous file handle was still open, an hence the deletion could not yet complete and was just queued. So now I try to close any open handle before calling `CreateFile`.

Here is now the working code:

```
#
# Monitors a directory for changes and pass the changes to the queue
#
def MonitorDirectory(self, out_queue):

    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' is watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))

    # File monitor
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

    overlapped          = pywintypes.OVERLAPPED()
    overlapped.hEvent   = win32event.CreateEvent(None, False, 0, None)

    buffer  = win32file.AllocateReadBuffer(1024 * 64)

    # Main loop to keep watching active
    while not self._shutdown.is_set():

        # Open directory
        try:    

            # Ensure handle is closed so delete event can fire and actually delete the folder
            try:
                win32file.CloseHandle(hDir)

            finally:
                hDir = win32file.CreateFile(self.path,
                                            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                            win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                            None,
                                            win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                            win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | win32con.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                            None)

                hDirPath = win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hDir, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED)

        except:

            print("Directory to monitor does not exist! Waiting...")

            # Wait before retry
            time.sleep(1)

        else:

            # Signal initialized event on queue, so the directory can be initialized
            out_queue.put((0, time.time(), None))

            # Monitor directory for changes
            while not self._shutdown.is_set():

                win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                                                buffer,
                                                True,
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
                                                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                                                overlapped,
                                                None)

                # Wait for the changes
                rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, 10000)

                # Detect move to Recycle bin
                try:
                    if hDirPath != win32file.GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hDir, win32con.FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED):

                        # Set watched dir as deleted (FileAction: 2 = delete)
                        out_queue.put( (2, time.time(), self.path) )

                        # Exits loop and wait for reinit
                        break;

                except:

                    print("Error: directory removed or invalid handle...")
                    break;


                if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                    try:
                        bytes_returned = win32file.GetOverlappedResult(hDir, overlapped, True)

                    except:
                        print("Error: directory removed or invalid handle...")
                        break;

                    else:

                        # Get the changes
                        for action, file in win32file.FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION(buffer, bytes_returned):
                            out_queue.put((action, time.time(), os.path.join(self.path, file)))

                elif rc == win32event.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\': Timeout, no actions".format(self.name))

                else:
                    print("Error?! RC = {0}".format(rc))
                    break

    # Done main loop
    print("Monitoring instance \'{0}\' has finished watching directory: {1}".format(self.name, self.path))
```