# win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't find all moved files

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi, pywin32

Good morning,

I've come across a peculiar problem with a program I'm creating in Python. It appears that when I drag and drop files from one location to another, not all of the files are registered as events by the modules.

I've been working with win32file and win32con to try an get all events related to moving files from one location to another for processing.

Here is a snip bit of my detection code:

```
import win32file
import win32con
def main():
    path_to_watch = 'D:\\'
    _file_list_dir = 1
    # Create a watcher handle
    _h_dir = win32file.CreateFile(
        path_to_watch,
        _file_list_dir,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ |
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        None
    )
    while 1:
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            _h_dir,
            1024,
            True,
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
            None,
            None
        )
        for _action, _file in results:
            if _action == 1:
                print 'found!'
            if _action == 2:
                print 'deleted!'
```

I dragged and dropped 7 files and it only found 4.

```
# found!
# found!
# found!
# found!
```

What can I do to detect all dropped files?

Comment: What's the `results` content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[ActiveState.Docs]: win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32file__ReadDirectoryChangesW_meth.html) (this is the best documentation that I could find for [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)) is a wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: ReadDirectoryChangesW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw). Here's what it states (about the buffer):

#### 1. General

> When you first call **ReadDirectoryChangesW**, the system allocates a buffer to store change information. This buffer is associated with the directory handle until it is closed and its size does not change during its lifetime. Directory changes that occur between calls to this function are added to the buffer and then returned with the next call. If the buffer overflows, the entire contents of the buffer are discarded, the *lpBytesReturned* parameter contains zero, and the **ReadDirectoryChangesW** function fails with the error code **ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR**.

- **My understanding** is that this is a **different** buffer than the one passed as an argument (*lpBuffer*):

  - The former is passed to every call of *ReadDirectoryChangesW* (could be different buffers (with **different sizes**) passed for each call)
  - The latter is allocated by the system, when the former clearly is allocated (by the user) before the function call 
    and **that is the one** that stores data (probably in some raw format) between function calls, and when the function is called, the buffer contents is copied (and formatted) to *lpBuffer* (if not overflew (and discarded) in the meantime)

#### 2. Synchronous

> Upon successful synchronous completion, the *lpBuffer* parameter is a formatted buffer and the number of bytes written to the buffer is available in *lpBytesReturned*. If the number of bytes transferred is zero, the buffer was either too large for the system to allocate or too small to provide detailed information on all the changes that occurred in the directory or subtree. In this case, you should compute the changes by enumerating the directory or subtree.

- This somewhat confirms my previous assumption

  - "*the buffer was either too large for the system to allocate*" - maybe when the buffer from previous point is allocated, it takes into account *nBufferLength*?

Anyway, I took your code and changed it "a bit".

*code00.py*:

```py
import sys
import msvcrt
import pywintypes
import win32file
import win32con
import win32api
import win32event


FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
FILE_ACTION_ADDED = 0x00000001
FILE_ACTION_REMOVED = 0x00000002

ASYNC_TIMEOUT = 5000

BUF_SIZE = 65536


def get_dir_handle(dir_name, asynch):
    flags_and_attributes = win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS
    if asynch:
        flags_and_attributes |= win32con.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
    dir_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
        dir_name,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        (win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ |
         win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
         win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE),
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        flags_and_attributes,
        None
    )
    return dir_handle


def read_dir_changes(dir_handle, size_or_buf, overlapped):
    return win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        dir_handle,
        size_or_buf,
        True,
        (win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY),
        overlapped,
        None
    )


def handle_results(results):
    for item in results:
        print("    {} {:d}".format(item, len(item[1])))
        _action, _ = item
        if _action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
            print("    found!")
        if _action == FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
            print("    deleted!")


def esc_pressed():
    return msvcrt.kbhit() and ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27


def monitor_dir_sync(dir_handle):
    idx = 0
    while True:
        print("Index: {:d}".format(idx))
        idx += 1
        results = read_dir_changes(dir_handle, BUF_SIZE, None)
        handle_results(results)
        if esc_pressed():
            break


def monitor_dir_async(dir_handle):
    idx = 0
    buffer = win32file.AllocateReadBuffer(BUF_SIZE)
    overlapped = pywintypes.OVERLAPPED()
    overlapped.hEvent = win32event.CreateEvent(None, False, 0, None)
    while True:
        print("Index: {:d}".format(idx))
        idx += 1
        read_dir_changes(dir_handle, buffer, overlapped)
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, ASYNC_TIMEOUT)
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            bufer_size = win32file.GetOverlappedResult(dir_handle, overlapped, True)
            results = win32file.FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION(buffer, bufer_size)
            handle_results(results)
        elif rc == win32event.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            #print("    timeout...")
            pass
        else:
            print("Received {:d}. Exiting".format(rc))
            break
        if esc_pressed():
            break
    win32api.CloseHandle(overlapped.hEvent)


def monitor_dir(dir_name, asynch=False):
    dir_handle = get_dir_handle(dir_name, asynch)
    if asynch:
        monitor_dir_async(dir_handle)
    else:
        monitor_dir_sync(dir_handle)
    win32api.CloseHandle(dir_handle)


def main():
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    asynch = True
    print("Attempting {}ynchronous mode using a buffer {:d} bytes long...".format("As" if async else "S", BUF_SIZE))
    monitor_dir(".\\test", asynch=asynch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- Used constants wherever possible
- Split your code into functions so it's modular (and also to avoid duplicating it)
- Added *print* statements to increase output
- Added the **asynchronous** functionality (so the script doesn't hang forever if no activity in the *dir*)
- Added a way to exit when user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd> (of course in synchronous mode an event in the *dir* must also occur)
- Played with different values for different results

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>dir /b test
> 0123456789.txt
> 01234567890123456789.txt
> 012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
> 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>"C:\Install\x64\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Attempting Synchronous mode using a buffer 512 bytes long...
> Index: 0
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     deleted!
> Index: 1
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     deleted!
> Index: 2
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     deleted!
> Index: 3
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     deleted!
> Index: 4
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     deleted!
> Index: 5
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     deleted!
> Index: 6
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     deleted!
> Index: 7
>     (1, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     found!
> Index: 8
>     (3, u'0123456789.txt') 14
> Index: 9
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     found!
> Index: 10
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     found!
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     found!
> Index: 11
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     found!
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
> Index: 12
> Index: 13
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     found!
> Index: 14
> Index: 15
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     found!
> Index: 16
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
> Index: 17
>     (1, u'a') 1
>     found!
> Index: 18
>     (3, u'a') 1
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>"C:\Install\x64\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Attempting Synchronous mode using a buffer 65536 bytes long...
> Index: 0
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     deleted!
> Index: 1
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     deleted!
> Index: 2
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     deleted!
> Index: 3
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     deleted!
> Index: 4
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     deleted!
> Index: 5
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     deleted!
> Index: 6
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     deleted!
> Index: 7
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     deleted!
> Index: 8
>     (1, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     found!
> Index: 9
>     (3, u'0123456789.txt') 14
> Index: 10
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     found!
> Index: 11
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
> Index: 12
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     found!
> Index: 13
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
> Index: 14
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     found!
> Index: 15
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
> Index: 16
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     found!
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
> Index: 17
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     found!
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     found!
> Index: 18
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     found!
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     found!
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     found!
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
> Index: 20
>     (2, u'a') 1
>     deleted!
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>"C:\Install\x64\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Attempting Asynchronous mode using a buffer 512 bytes long...
> Index: 0
> Index: 1
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     deleted!
> Index: 2
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     deleted!
> Index: 3
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     deleted!
> Index: 4
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     deleted!
> Index: 5
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     deleted!
> Index: 6
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     deleted!
> Index: 7
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     deleted!
> Index: 8
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     deleted!
> Index: 9
>     (2, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     deleted!
> Index: 10
> Index: 11
> Index: 12
>     (1, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     found!
> Index: 13
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     found!
> Index: 14
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     found!
> Index: 15
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
> Index: 16
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     found!
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
> Index: 17
> Index: 18
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     found!
> Index: 19
> Index: 20
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     found!
> Index: 21
> Index: 22
> Index: 23
> Index: 24
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049799109>"C:\Install\x64\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Attempting Asynchronous mode using a buffer 65536 bytes long...
> Index: 0
> Index: 1
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     deleted!
> Index: 2
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     deleted!
> Index: 3
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     deleted!
> Index: 4
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     deleted!
> Index: 5
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     deleted!
> Index: 6
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     deleted!
> Index: 7
>     (2, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     deleted!
> Index: 8
>     (2, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     deleted!
>     (2, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     deleted!
> Index: 9
>     (2, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     deleted!
> Index: 10
> Index: 11
> Index: 12
>     (1, u'0123456789.txt') 14
>     found!
> Index: 13
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789.txt') 24
>     found!
> Index: 14
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     found!
> Index: 15
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 34
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
>     found!
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 44
> Index: 16
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     found!
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 54
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     found!
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 64
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     found!
> Index: 17
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 74
>     (1, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     found!
>     (3, u'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 84
>     (1, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     found!
>     (3, u'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 94
>     (1, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
>     found!
>     (3, u'0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.txt') 104
> Index: 18
> Index: 19
> ```

**Remarks**:

- Used a dir *test* containing 10 files with different names (repetitions of *0123456789*)
- There are 4 runs:

  1. Synchronous

     - *512B* buffer
     - *64K* buffer
  2. Asynchronous

     - *512B* buffer
     - *64K* buffer
- For each (above) run, the files are (using *Windows Commander* to operate):

  - Moved **from** the *dir* (involved *delete*)
  - Moved (back) **to** the *dir* (involved *add*)
- It's just one run for each combination, and that by far **can't be relied on as a benchmark**, but I ran the script several times and the pattern tends to be consistent
- Deleting files doesn't vary too much across runs, which means that the events are evenly distributed over (the tiny amounts of) time
- Adding files on the other hand is dependent on the buffer size. Another noticeable thing is that for each addition there are 2 events
- From performance perspective, asynchronous mode doesn't bring any improvements (as I was expecting), out of contrary, it tends to slow things down. But its biggest advantage it's the possibility of gracefully exit on timeout (**abnormal interrupt might keep resources locked** till program exit (and sometimes even beyond!))

**Bottom line is that there's no recipe to avoid losing events**. Every measure taken can be "beaten" by increasing the number of generated events.

Minimizing the losses:

- The buffer size. This was the (main) problem in your case. Unfortunately, the documentation couldn't be less clear, there are no guidelines on how large it should be. Browsing *C* forums I noticed that *64K* is a common value. However:

  - It isn't possible to have a huge buffer and in case of failures to decrease its size until success, because that would mean losing all the events generated while figuring out the buffer size
  - Even if *64k* is enough to hold (for several times) all the events that I generated in my tests, some were still lost. Maybe that's because of the "magical" buffer that I talked about, at the beginning
- Reduce the number of events as much as possible. In your case I noticed that you're only interested on add and delete events (*FILE_ACTION_ADDED* and *FILE_ACTION_REMOVED*). Only specify the appropriate *FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_** flags to *ReadDirectoryChangesW* (for example you don't care about *FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED*, but you are receiving it when adding files)
- Try splitting the *dir* contents in several subdirs and monitor them concurrently. For example if you only care about changes occurred in one *dir* and a bunch of its subdirs, there's no point in recursively monitoring the whole tree, because it will most likely produce lots of useless events. Anyway, if doing things in parallel, **don't use threads because of *GIL*!!!** ([[Python.Wiki]: GlobalInterpreterLock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). Use [[Python.Docs]: multiprocessing - Process-based “threading” interface](https://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead
- Increase the speed of the code that runs in the loop so it spends as little time as possible outside *ReadDirectoryChangesW* (when generated events could overflow the buffer). Of course, some of the items below might have insignificant influence and (also have some bad side effects) but I'm listing them anyway:

  - Do as less processing as possible and try to delay it. Maybe do it in another process (because of ***GIL***)
  - Get rid of all *print* like statements
  - Instead of e.g. *win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME* use *from win32con import FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME* at the beginning of the script, and only use *FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME* in the loop (to avoid variable lookup in the module)
  - Don't use functions (because of *call* / *ret* like instructions) - not sure about that
  - Try using *win32file.GetQueuedCompletionStatus* method to get the results (***async* only**)
  - Since in time, things tend to get better (there are exceptions, of course), try switching to a newer *Python* version. Maybe it will run faster
  - Use *C* - this is probably undesirable, but it could have some benefits:

    - There won't be the back and forth conversions between *Python* and *C* that *PyWin32* performs - but I didn't use a profiler to check how much time is spent in them
    - *lpCompletionRoutine* (that *PyWin32* doesn't offer) would be available too, maybe it's faster
    - As an alternative, *C* could be invoked using *CTypes*, but that would require some work and I feel that it won't worth

Comment: My apologies, I haven't had the time to look at this in full yet. Please allow me a few days to catch up on this and then I'll be able to answer correctly and provide the information you've requested.

Comment: I appreciate how incredibly detailed this is. Reading over it, it's a lot of information to process (I'm fairly new to the pywin32 module with all the win32 components). Thank you so much for thoroughly explaining all possible ways to optimize my code and ways to properly search through these directories in an efficient way.

Comment: You're welcome :) . I no longer need the `result` contents, since I was able to reproduce the problem on my side.

Comment: Just as a disclaimer, it appears you were correct regarding buffersize. I haven't fully tested it yet (as I'm still incorporating the new code into my own project, reading through and dissecting), but it could also be due in part by my code watching a server for updates.

Comment: Also, I wish I could aware bonus points for PEP-8. :P I love it. It works really well for me so far! Thank you so much for your contribution, @CristiFati

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand this correctly... I pre-apologize for derailing a bit... 0x0001 is a 16-bit reference, 0x00000001 is a 32-bit reference... is listing the directory really a 16-bit operation and if so, are the actions which a file takes truly 32-bit? It seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: By default, *Python* Will convert them to its internal `int`. I defined them like that because that's how they are defined on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com) (for clarity).

Comment: Thank you! And thank you doubly for providing that reference.

Comment: What a great answer.  You closely read the question, then designed a reasonable experiment.  You provide detailed results.  This post helped me to more deeply under this Win32 API: `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`.  Thank you!