# NetFileEnum is being inconsistent, occasionally returns no data

Tags: windows, winapi, netapi32

I am working on a C++ application that detects changes happening on a shared folder (using `ReadDirectoryChangesW`) and call `NetFileEnum` on that modified file/folder. This way, I know the possible candidates modifying file/folder.

According to `NetFileEnum` docs:

> Returns information about some or all *open* files on a server, depending on the parameters specified.

However, NetFileEnum is not consistent, it does not always tell me who is currently accessing the resource. It seems to work only 50-60% of the time.

More specifically, say I modify `\\172.20.30.40\myshare\file.txt` (local path: `C:\myshare\file.txt`).
`NetFileEnum` is then called with the following parameters:

```
fStatus = NetFileEnum(L"\\\\172.20.30.40",
            (LPWSTR)szLocalPathStr.c_str(), // C:\\myshare\\file.txt
            pszUserName,                    // NULL
            dLevel,                         // 3
            (LPBYTE*)&pFile,
            dPrefMaxLen,
            &dEntriesRead,
            &dTotalEntries,
            NULL);
```

`fStatus` returns `NERR_success` (0). However, 40-50% of the time, `dEntriesRead` is 0. Is this a known issue with NetFileEnum? Is there a more consistent way to know who all are accessing a shared resource?

Comment: `(LPWSTR)szLocalPathStr.c_str()` is a potential bug. Either use a `const_cast` or pass `szLocalPathStr.data()`, calling [std::string::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) in place of `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: You might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799109/win32file-readdirectorychangesw-doesnt-find-all-moved-files. I haven't worked with *NetFileEnum* for years, but something doesn't seem right about the 1st 2 parameters.

Comment: @CristiFati I consulted the MSDN docs for NetFileEnum and I don't find anything unusual. I could remove \\ before server name though.

Comment: I initially made a confusion, I thought that the 2nd argument should be the share name, but it's not the case. I've recently tested it from *Python* and it works if the server name contains simply the IP (or *NULL*), and the 2nd arg contains the absolute path. I also pasted an *URL* to an answer that I provided regarding *ReadDirectoryChangesW* (which is most likely the cause for some events being lost).

Comment: @CristiFati Passing server name as NULL implies local machine. Also, I am aware of the problem with ReadDirectoryChangesW, I use a buffered and asynchronous version. The problem here is with NetFileEnum, and I am still looking for a solution.