# Run function when a file is externally closed python

Tags: python, file, winapi, operating-system

I am trying to run a function when a .txt file is closed. This file is opened in notepad using `os.startfile()`. Before using this I tried to using `subprocess` like this:

```
import subprocess

def on_file_closed():
    print("The external file has been closed")

path2file = "path/to/your/file.txt"

process = subprocess.Popen(['open', path2file])

process.wait()
on_file_closed()
```

This code returns the error `[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, and apparently this is because the file is not a .exe file. I then tried the following code which I belive is more promising:

```
import os
import win32file
import win32con

def on_file_closed():
    print("The external file has been closed")

path2file = "path/to/your/file.txt"

os.startfile(path2file)

file_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    path2file,
    win32con.GENERIC_READ,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    None,
    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    None
)

while True:
    results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        file_handle,
        4096,
        True,
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
        None,
        None
    )

    if results[0][0] == 0x00000002 or results[0][0] == 0x00000003:
        on_file_closed()
        break
```

This code returns the error returns the error `(87, 'ReadDirectoryChangesW', 'The parameter is incorrect.')`. Is there a way for me to fix this error or is there another more simple method I can use? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Check here for how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799109/win32file-readdirectorychangesw-doesnt-find-all-moved-files

Comment: *"I am trying to run a function when a .txt file is closed."* - Please be specific what *"file is closed"* means to you. I'm having a feeling that what you're asking for is not the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable When the file is closed in notepad, I want to run `on_file_closed()`

Comment: @IInspectable Firstly I acknowledged that my first attempt at solving my issue didn't work and I explain why I thought it didn't work. Secondly, `win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW()` can be used for retrieving information about any changes made to a directory, such as file and folder creations, modifications, deletions, and renames. This is why I posted the question, because I was using a function that could work, I was just using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just explicitly execute notepad? Your original code works if you replace `open` with `notepad`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

```py
import subprocess

def on_file_closed():
    print("The external file has been closed")

path2file = "path/to/your/file.txt"

process = subprocess.Popen(['notepad', path2file])

process.wait()
on_file_closed()
```

Comment: Works but the function is run immediatly, Im guessing thats because the process doesn't wait for notepad to be finished

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. I just tried it again, and the function is only run once Notepad has been closed or its process ended.

Comment: It seems the issue was something else to do woth my code, standalone the code works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't answer the (fuzzy) question. `process.wait()` returns once the given process has terminated. That has literally no bearing on which file(s) (if any) have been modified during the lifetime of that process. The tough part about problem solving is *identifying* the problem. This hasn't happened (neither in the question nor in this proposed answer).

Comment: I assumed, seemingly correctly, that the questioner didn't really want to know how to run a function after `CloseHandle` is called with a file handle.

Comment: Since the questioner never actually clarified, *what* they need, there's nothing indicating whether this actually is a solution to an undisclosed problem. It's not unreasonable to assume that they don't even know what the problem is. After all, they provided code that solves two vastly different, unrelated problems.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` is the python API to execute commands. If you are opening a `.txt` file, in Windows it is opened with Notepad by default. In this case `Popen` should call the program instead of just `open` (since `open` is not recognised as a valid command in Windows).

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe', "file.txt"])
```

Hope this helps.